# FindRoot fails 100 iteration precision

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, variable-definitions, approximation, command-line

I am attempting to find roots of a complex equation that involves exponential functions and small approximation values. I have had success using `FindRoot` for values that are simple and positive, but Mathematica does not like it when the values I enter are negative and rather small:

```
FindRoot[(Exp[2 h] - 1 - 2 h)/(5 h^2) == 0.002, {h, -200}]  
(* {h -> -199.499} *) 

FindRoot[(Exp[2 h] - 1 - 2 h)/(5 h^2) == (-0.0001), {h, 480}]  
(* FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the 
   requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. *)
```

I am unsure whether I should just change my input values or use another method of determining a good number. If I use any small number or negative value, it will fail to produce an answer and give me a *`FindRoot::lstol`* error.

Comment: What makes you think there are any values of `h` for which the expression is negative?

Comment: To make it a bit more exlicit: The function `Exp[2 h]` is convex and you subtract its tangent a `h = 0` and divide by a nonnegative term. Thus, you function is `0` at `h=0` and positive everywhere else. So, your second equation has no solution, so Mathematica can try as hard as she can; she will inevitably fail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue arose from trying to solve an unsolvable equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask Mathematica if it can tell you something about your function and in particular if it is going to be negative somewhere

```
Reduce[(Exp[2 h] - 1 - 2 h)/(5 h^2) < 0, h]
(* False *)
```

As you can see, there is no way your function will ever be negative. Therefore, it is no error in `FindRoot` but in your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose my standard values that were given would require me to explain that fact.